# Php array value check in html upload form

Tags: php

I can check a simple variable if it's empty or not. But how do i check the array value which is come from Html Upload Form. Like: **name=images[];**

Simple variable check:

```
if(empty($somevalue))
  $err[] = "your variable is empty";
```

But how do i check if it's something like this:

```
<input name="images[]" type="file"/>
```

**Update Code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && $_POST['Submit'] == "Save & Continue")
{
$number_of_file_fields = 0;
$number_of_uploaded_files = 0;
$number_of_moved_files = 0;
$uploaded_files = array();
$upload_directory = dirname(__file__) . '/uploaded/'; //set upload directory

$img[] = $_FILES['images']['name']; 
$img = array();
$err = array();

if(isset($img))
{
    if(empty($img)) 
        $err[] = "Your property picture require";           
}

if(!empty($err))
{
    foreach($err as $er)
    {
        echo $er;
    }   
}
else
{
    echo "done";    
}

}

?>
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"   
name="mutiple_file_upload_form" id="mutiple_file_upload_form">
<table width="1020" border="0" cellspacing="7" cellpadding="0">   
 <tr>
 <td valign="top" width="250">
     Upload your property pictures
     </td>
     <td>
      <div id="file_container">
        <input name="images[]" type="file" class="tr2"  />
        <br />
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="add_file_field();">Add another</a><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Save & Continue" name="Submit" class="submit" />
      </td>
 </tr> 
 </table>
</form> 
</table>
```

Comment: You know about `$_FILES` and `$_POST`, right?

Comment: I'd encourage you to [read the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `empty()` on an array.

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ...
>   array() (an empty array)
>   ...

However, you should note that `empty()` will return `false` for an array with *empty* elements. Look into [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) if you need to consider this.

Comment: Well, @Jason McCreary I updated my code. Plz see this, it's may be wrong. But i actually want to check that it's upload something.

Answer (score 0):

You simply ignore the square backets on the PHP side

`if empty($_POST['images'])`